# "Strange" characters when saving to PDF

Tags: html, character

I have this pdf file:

SA Pias - Margaça Branco.pdf

I use this to access it:

href="SA Pias - Marga%E7a Branco.pdf"

It opens OK in the browser, but when the user is going to save it, those "strange" characters appears.

Is there any way to appear the real name (SA Pias - Margaça Branco.pdf) when the user is going to save the pdf?

Comment: What are "those strange characters"?

Comment: This is a question of character encoding being different on your systems. Question: what encoding do you use where? how do you specify the name of the file for download?

Comment: I think the name is mentioned in the question: **SA Pias - Margaça Branco.pdf**

Comment: The file to download is
SA Pias - Margaça Branco.pdf
The user opens the file in the browser, and I use this code
href="SA Pias - Marga%E7a Branco.pdf"
With this code, the server can see the file, but when downloading the name is like the link in the browser
http://www.sapias-vinhos.com/Working/Vinhos/SA%20Pias%20-%20Marga%E7a%20Branco.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Could you use PHP ?

If yes,

You only need to change the link to something like:

```
href="file.php?strName=Branco"
```

Then on the file.php
You will have to add:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="SA Pias - Margaça Branco.pdf"');
```

Comment: Not only I have that PDF, but I also have about six others like that, then I have to create for each pdf a file01.php, file02.php?

Comment: That almost did it. It did download with the correct name, but when I was going to open the pdf an error appeared, "Could not open... the file may be damaged or wasn't correctly decoded"

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578349/while-downloading-filenames-from-non-english-languages-are-not-getting-displayed/2578617#2578617. Also check this link: http://blog.fastmail.fm/2011/06/24/download-non-english-filenames/

Comment: Yes!!!! Done it!

I used

href="SAPias%20-%20Marga%E7a%20Branco.pdf"

I didn't need to use PHP.

Comment: Well... almost. If the "ç" isn't there, it goes well but with "ç" in there, the final .pdf is
SA%20Pias%20-%20Marga%E7a%20Branco.pdf
It only happens on-line, when I test it locally all goes well.